# Parse - Compound queries with OR and AND?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

basically I want to do something similar to

```
SELECT * FROM FriendRequests WHERE (from == user OR to == user) AND status = "accepted"
```

There is  method called `orQueryWithSubqueries` which allows me to combine the two ors, but I can't figure how to perform an AND between those and the status query.

```
let statusCheck = FriendRequest.query()
statusCheck.whereKey("status", equalTo: FriendRequest.Status.Accepted.rawValue)

let userCheckOne = FriendRequest.query()
userCheckOne.whereKey("from", equalTo: User.currentUser())

let userCheckTwo = FriendRequest.query()
userCheckOne.whereKey("to", equalTo: User.currentUser())

let userCheck = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([userCheckOne, userCheckTwo])

// Some how do (userCheck AND statusCheck)
```

Comment: Hi I am curious about the FriendRequest.Status.Accepted.rawValue , is this something in your code or Parse Table or both? I have the same question if you can elaborate that would be great! @aryaxt

Comment: @kareem That's just an enum. The values in parse are stored as string and on client I have an enum Named Status inside a class namedFriendRequest . Probably could be simplified to .Accepted.rawValue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're coming at it from a SQL angle, think of the `OR` query more like a `UNION` statement.

Your query would then look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM FriendRequests
WHERE from = user
AND status = "accepted"

UNION

SELECT *
FROM FriendRequests
WHERE to = user
AND status = "accepted"
```

As you can see the solution is to simply add the `AND` part to both your queries:

```
let userCheckOne = FriendRequest.query()
userCheckOne.whereKey("from", equalTo: User.currentUser())
userCheckOne.whereKey("status", equalTo: FriendRequest.Status.Accepted.rawValue)

let userCheckTwo = FriendRequest.query()
userCheckTwo.whereKey("to", equalTo: User.currentUser())
userCheckTwo.whereKey("status", equalTo: FriendRequest.Status.Accepted.rawValue)

let userCheck = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([userCheckOne, userCheckTwo])
```

Comment: Ooooh got it. I found out that it's also possible to use Predicate. Will give that a try and get back. Wondering if the following predicate works "status == %@ AND (from == %@ OR to == %@)"

Comment: how u use the predicate? with parse.. Please give example